# Using an Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with Apache Flink

Tags: kryo, apache-flink

While using Apache Flink with the following code:

```java
DataStream<List<String>> result = source.window(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).mapWindow(new WindowMapFunction<String, List<String>>() {

    @Override
    public void mapWindow(Iterable<String> iterable, Collector<List<String>> collector) throws Exception {
        List<String> top5 = Ordering.natural().greatestOf(iterable, 5);
        collector.collect(top5);
    }
}).flatten();
```

I got this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:116)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:211)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamRecordSerializer.deserialize(StreamRecordSerializer.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.streamrecord.StreamRecordSerializer.deserialize(StreamRecordSerializer.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.plugable.NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.read(NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.serialization.SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.getNextRecord(SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.java:125)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I ue the `UnmodifiableCollection` with Flink?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that the default `CollectionSerializer` of Kryo can not deserialize the collection again, because its not modifiable (the `.add()` call fails).

To resolve the issue, we can use the `UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer` from the [kryo-serializers](https://github.com/magro/kryo-serializers) project. Flink transitively depends on the project, so there is no need to add it as a dependency.

Next, we have to register the serializer with Flink's Kryo instances.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
Class<?> unmodColl = Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection");
see.getConfig().addDefaultKryoSerializer(unmodColl, UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.class);
```

Usually, we don't have to call `Class.forName()` for registering a serializer, but in this case, `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection` is package visible, so we can not directly access the class.

Comment: thanks for this insightful and prompt answer. Your answering speed is staggering :-)

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks Robert!

Comment: great! it works fine. I meet two unmoficable exception: UnmodifiableCollection and UnmodifiableMap

Answer (score 3):

you can try this one since kryo-serializers repo did not change for the last few years.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val avroKryoSerializerUtil = new AvroKryoSerializerUtils
avroKryoSerializerUtil.addAvroSerializersIfRequired(env.getConfig,classOf[GenericData.Record])
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a valid answer and can be helpful:

https://lists.apache.org/thread/8f21loz5915dzw8cy2q8c08kxypvj1sq

> I would recommend using the AvroSerializer for serializing
> GenericRecords. You have to add org.apache.flink:flink-avro as a
> dependency to your job and then tell the system that you would like to
> use the GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo via
>
> DataStream sourceStream = env.addSource(new
> AvroGenericSource()) .returns(new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(schema));
>
> You can find more information about it here [1].

[1]
https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html#avro