# PoJo to Avro Serialization throw KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

My Unit test was running OK under Flink 1.11.2 with parquet-avro 1.10.0, once I upgrade to 1.12.0 with parquet-avro 1.12.0, my unit test will throw

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Serialization trace:
reserved (org.apache.avro.Schema$Field)
fieldMap (org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema)
schema (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:143) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:21) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
...

aused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1057) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:109) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106) ~[kryo-2.24.0.jar:?]
    ... 27 more
```

My Unit test code snippet is something like below:

```
private ImmutableList<PoJo> testData = ImmutableList.of(
            PoJo.build("123", "0.0.0.0", null),
            PoJo.build("123", "0.0.0.1", 2L)
    );

DataStream<PoJo> input = env
                .addSource(new TestSource(testData), PojoTypeInfo.of(PoJo.class))
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy);

DataStream<GenericRecord> output = input
                .map(TestClass::convertPoJoToGenericRecord)
                .returns(new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(PoJo.getAvroSchema()));

output.addSink();
```

The function is something like

```
GenericRecord convertPoJoToGenericRecord(PoJo pojo) throws Exception {
        Schema schema = PoJo.getAvroSchema();
        GenericRecordBuilder builder = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);
        for (Schema.Field field : schema.getFields()) {
            builder.set(field.name(), TestClass.getObjectField(field, pojo));
        }
        GenericRecord record = builder.build();
        return record;
    }
```

Can anyone help on this?

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is related to the usage of `ImmutableList` together with Kryo: when deserializing, Kryo is trying to create an empty `List` and add stuff to it, which of course cannot work. This issue has been answered before in SO => I'll close this as duplicate and mention an link to the other one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453030/using-an-collectionsunmodifiablecollection-with-apache-flink)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a valid answer and can be helpful:

https://lists.apache.org/thread/8f21loz5915dzw8cy2q8c08kxypvj1sq

> I would recommend using the AvroSerializer for serializing GenericRecords.
> You have to add org.apache.flink:flink-avro as a dependency to your job and
> then tell the system that you would like to use
> the GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo via
>
> DataStream sourceStream = env.addSource(new
> AvroGenericSource()) .returns(new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(schema));
>
> You can find more information about it here [1].

[1]
https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html#avro